# Watir Measure Page Performance

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

Ive found this gem : http://watirwebdriver.com/page-performance/

But i cant seem to understand what this measures

```
browser.performance.summary[:response_time]/1000
```

Does it start measuring from the second i open the browser?

```
Watir::Browser.new :chrome
```

or from the last Watir-webdriver command writen?

And how can i set when it starts the timer?

** I've tried several scripts but i keep getting `0 seconds`
Thats why im not sure.**

Comment: If you do not get an answer here, ask at github: https://github.com/90kts/watir-webdriver-performance/issues

Comment: Thanks , ill try there as well .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I have read (I have not actually used it on a project), the response_time is the time from starting navigation to the end of the page loading - see Tim's (the gem's author) answer in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711653/what-is-the-difference-between-response-time-time-to-first-byte-and-time-to). The graphical image on Tim's blog will helps to understand the different values - http://90kts.com/2011/04/19/watir-webdriver-performance-gem-released/.

The gem is for getting performance results of single response, rather than overall usage of a browser during a script. So there is no need to start/stop the timer.

If you are getting 0 seconds, it likely means that the response_time is less than 1000 milliseconds (ie in Ruby, doing 999/1000 gives 0). To make sure you are getting something non-zero, try doing:

```
browser.performance.summary[:response_time]/1000.0
```

Dividing by 1000.0 will ensure that you get the decimal values (eg 0.013).