# how to measure load time in watir-webdriver for firefox

Tags: performance, watir-webdriver

I need to do performance testing by measuring the load time on click and navigation in application. I used Watir-webdriver-performance gem. It works for Chrome and not supporting firefox. Please let me know any guidance on how to do it on firefox?

Thanks

Comment: Off the top of my head, I would either see chrome is supposed and add support for Firefox OR write a page load function into your framework to measure it.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it:

```
require 'watir-webdriver-performance'

$response = $browser.performance.summary[:response_time]
$first_byte = $browser.performance.summary[:time_to_first_byte]
$last_byte = $browser.performance.summary[:time_to_last_byte]

def performance_check
    puts ("#{$browser.url}: Response time: #{$response}ms.")

    puts ("#{$browser.url}: Time to first byte: #{$first_byte}ms.")

    puts ("#{$browser.url}: Time to last byte: #{$last_byte}ms.")
end

def test_site_01
  $browser.goto("http://www.google.com/")
  performance_check 
end
```

See my question about the watir-webdriver-performance gem. The developer of the gem responds with the differences between time to first/last and response time.

[What is the difference between :response_time, :time_to_first_byte, and :time_to_last_byte in watir-webdriver-performance gem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711653/what-is-the-difference-between-response-time-time-to-first-byte-and-time-to)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as well before i found about the performance gem.

I found an element that appears only when the load action completed

and waited for it to be available with:

```
browser.element.present?
```

Im aware its a really rough workaround , but that was the only thing i thought of.
And it gives you a rough estimate about the action time.